# Why is Size an unknown type?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm trying to implement some code in the PCL project of a cross-platform solution. When I try to specify a Size, it is an unknown type. And to make things worse, I cannot create a new Bitmap either using 2 parameters?

Specific errors:

`Error CS1070: The type 'System.Drawing.Size' has been forwarded to an assembly that is not referenced.`

`The type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' does not contain a constructor that takes`2' arguments`

The PCL project is targeting .Net 4.5 as shown below the code.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

namespace ACS.FundRaising
{
    public class CheckServices
    {
        public CheckServices()
        {
        }

        public static Byte[] DetectCheck(Byte[] imageData, int width, int height)
        {
            if (imageData == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            // convert to Bitmap
            var stream = new MemoryStream(imageData);
            Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);
            Size size;
            size.width = width;
            size.height = height;

            var bitmap = new Bitmap(image,size);

            // do other work here, replace null with appropriate object

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: PCL Project build options]

Comment: `System.Drawing.Bitmap` is not available for all the listed platforms. Intellisense offers it, but I doubt that it would be available on android or IOS

Comment: I thought that was the whole point of doing all this in Xamarin. So .Net framework objects were available in the target platforms too.

Comment: In regards to the .Net framework, there are a number of Classes, or items missing from Classes, that do not have a full xplat implementation. System.Drawing.* is one of them. There are third-party PCL and non-PCL libs (closed and open-source) that cover a lot of ground here. It just depends upon what you need a 'bitmap' for, with the understanding that a bitmap structure means nothing to native iOS or Andriod

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin for iOS contains a definition for [`System.Drawing.Size`](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Drawing.Size/). On the other hand, please be aware that the `System.Drawing` namespace relies on GDI+, which is not available under the shared cross-plat framework (only on Windows).

Hence, there is no `System.Drawing.Bitmap` in Xamarin.iOS.